Track two live GPS in QGIS
Does anyone know how to display the output of multiple GPS devices at the same time in QGIS for live-tracking in the field?
I have two GPS devices that are both outputting NMEA sentences through either a serial com port or over a network connection.
I can plot either one on its own, but not both together.
